# How to start a QT programm without copying the dll files

Tags: c++, cmake, qt5.5

I wrote a little Qt program (on Windows) and I met the following situation:

With CMake, I generated my make files to build the Program as follows

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(helloworld)

SET(C++_STD_FLAG "c++11" CACHE STRING "e.g. c++98,c++11,c++14,...")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=${C++_STD_FLAG}")

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
find_package(Qt5Widgets)

add_executable(main main.cxx)
target_link_libraries(main Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Gui Qt5::Core)
```

If I want to start the "main.exe", it appears a message that some DLL's are not found. The DLL's are Qt5Widget.dll, Qt5Core.dll, Qt5Gui.dll. If I copy them to the same folder as the "main.exe" everything work fine.

How can I launch the "main.exe" without copying the DLL's into the directory?

**EDIT:** The path, where the DLL is, is already added to the PATH variable in windows. However, it does not work.

**EDIT:** I also append my code of the main.cpp

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc,char **argv){
  QApplication app(argc,argv);
  QWidget window;
  window.setWindowTitle("Hallo Qt");
  QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Ende");
  QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
  layout->addWidget(button);
  window.setLayout(layout);
  window.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

**EDIT:** I found the problem, but this raise a furhter question:
I also have installed PyQt, which had a higher priority in the PATH variable. So I made the other Qt installation a higher and it worked.

But, How can I tell an executable file to use a specific DLL? Because, if I compile the program with Qt Creater it works even if the PyQt has a higher priority in the PATH variable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried restarting your computer after adding the DLLs path to your PATH variable? because that should work, you sometime only need to relaunch explorer, or whatever, after updating the PATH variable.

Comment: I restarted my pc, but still the same. In the post above, I also appended my c++ code. My operating system is Windows 10 and I use the MinGW compiler which is included in the QT package.

Comment: Use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check where the linker tries to find required libraries. See Options -> Configure Module Search Order.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I found the problem, but this raises a new question. Therefore I edited my question.

Comment: I think you have some control over the directories with a `qt.conf` file in the directory of your .exe. See: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-conf.html.

Comment: Now, I recognized that the actual problem is not PyQt, it is the Miktex binary folder. I tried the qt.conf file, but I got the same error (except I swtich the paths in the PATH variablen, then it works)

Comment: The problem with qt.conf could be, that Qt only can read it if it is already loaded. My only solution is to put the path in a higher priority, so that these DLL's will used at first.